# HTML select with size > 1 in iPad

Tags: javascript, html, ipad

I have a site done to work in windows browsers. There are select boxes with a size atribute > 1.

I run it in iPad and at start if no element selected select box showed empty. After clicking on it I can't select first item of the list. The Safari perhaps thinks that first item already selected and does nothing.

I have fixed this by javascript - after DOM ready I check userAgent and for iPad set size = 1. And at start first element already selected. But I don't need this.

Are any solution for this issue without javascript?

Thanks

Comment: You may try to add a dummy option before the others and use a class(or style) with `display: none`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it isn't resolve the issue. I tried it in iPad but hidden option is displayed to.